# Unexpected "(" in nested ifelse R

Tags: r, rstudio

I am trying to run the following line of code in R

```
new <- data.frame(newdb, 
                ifelse(newdb$centile >=0 & newdb$centile < 3,"1",
                ifelse(newdb$centile >=3 & newdb$centile < 6,"2",
                       ifelse(newdb$centile >=6 & newdb$centile < 9,"3","4"))))
```

But i am getting the following error

> Error: unexpected ')' in "ifelse(newdb$centile >=6 & newdb$centile < >9,"3","4"))"

Comment: You have an extra `)` as per the error.   Please check it before posting it.  Also, you can use `with` and avoid multiple `newdb$`.  BTW this can be solved more easily with `cut` i..e `cut(newdb$centile, breaks=c(-Inf,0,3,6,9,Inf))` There is a `labels` argument in `cut`, where you can specify the replacement values

Comment: I know, but I am unable to find any extra ")" in my LOC. Is my syntax correct?

Comment: Thank you! The problem was with data.frame

Comment: I didn't find any problem by `data.frame(newdb, res)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't need a nested `ifelse`.  It can be solved much easier with `cut` by specifying the `breaks`.

```
res1 <- cut(newdb$centile, breaks=c(-Inf, 0, 3, 6, 9, Inf),
                  right=FALSE, labels=FALSE)-1
```

OP's code with `ifelse`

```
res <- ifelse(newdb$centile >=0 & newdb$centile < 3,"1", 
          ifelse(newdb$centile >=3 & newdb$centile < 6,"2", 
            ifelse(newdb$centile >=6 & newdb$centile < 9,"3","4")))  

identical(as.numeric(res), res1)
#[1] TRUE
```

If we want to create a new column ('group') in the original dataset,

```
 newdb$group <- res
```

Also, the multiple `newdb$` in the OP's code can be avoided by using `with`

```
  with(newdb,
          ifelse(centile >=0 & centile < 3, '1',
            ifelse(centile >=3 & centile < 6, '2',
              ifelse(centile >=6 & centile < 9, '3', '4'))))
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
newdb <- data.frame(centile= sample(5:12, 25, replace=TRUE))
```